# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, netlify, unexpected-token

I uploaded my react project to Netlify but when I clicked on the link nothing came out and there was the following error in the console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

How can I fix this?

```
Build settings
Base directory: Not set
Build command: CI= npm run build
Publish directory: build
Deploy log visibility: Logs are public
Builds: Active
```

Comment: Sounds similar to an error one would get when attempting to parse html string as json: `JSON.parse("<html/>")`. Check the network logs carefully, one of your requests may be erroring out

Comment: Try building the application locally and serve it through `serve` (npm i serve). That will replicate the deployed version of Netlify into local. So that you will be able to replicate the actual error